# Angular interpret {{}} inside a link function of a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

Is there a way to interpret the content of a div having my directive as an attribute :

example :

```
 <div my-directive>{{1+1}}</div>
```

and my link function looks like this :

```
  link = (scope, element, attrs) =>
  interpretedString = element.text()
```

in this example `interpretedString`  is equal to `{{1+1}}` instead of 2

any help? the `scope.$eval` evaluates attributes, but what if I want to evaluate the text of a directive?

thanks

Comment: Try usage of $interpolate service

Comment: Seems strange to want to take this from `element.text()`. I suspect that using `$timeout` to delay the call until after angular has completed the interpolation would also work, but relying on the DOM in this way suggests, to me, something odd with your design...

Comment: well the problem is that I am storing markdown string inside an array, and then I use an external lib, showdown to generate the dom from a markdown String. thats why I need to interpret the elements string so I can retranslate it using showdoown, not the templating system built into angluar.

Comment: Mik378 can you please post it as an answer so I can +1 you? :)

Comment: transclude the content?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to interpret the string, you need to interpolate it thanks to the angular's [`$interpolate`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24interpolate) service.

Example:

```
link = (scope, element, attrs) =>
  interpretedString = $interpolate(element.text())(scope)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to back up a bit, the contents of an element could be anything -- an array of element trees, text nodes, comments, and (unless you declare your directive "terminal") it all gets evaluated recursively and could have directives inside directive. I think you'd be much better off passing an interpolated string as an attribute. I mean you *could* do it this way, but whoever's using your widget wouldn't really expect that.

Something like:

```
<div my-directive my-attr="{{1+1}}"></div>
```

Or even (if that attribute is "primary"):

```
<div my-directive="{{1+1}}"></div>
```

From there, instead of `$interpolate(element.text())(scope)` you'd have `$interpolate(attrs.myDirective)(scope)`

Of course, the nature of Angular is everything is dynamic and can update all the time. What if the expression didn't just have constants, as a real expression likely wouldn't. If it were:

```
{{1+foo}}
```

Then the question is do you care about it changing? If not, $interpolate is fine. It captures the initial value. If you do care about it updating, you should use $observe.

```
attrs.$observe('myDirective', function(val) {
    // if say "foo" is 5, val would be 6 here
});
```

Then later if you're like `scope.foo = 8` the callback runs and passes `9`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative is to do

```
<my-directive ng-bind="1+1" />

var two = $scope.$eval('ngBind');
```

:-p

```
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngBind : '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('expecting string "1+1": '+attrs.ngBind);
            console.log('expecting evaluated string "2": '+scope.$eval('ngBind'));
        }
    };
});
```

*side note*: `<div ng-bind="val"></div>` is almost the same as `<div>{{val}}</div>`. Except that u save 4 brackets and never see them flashing into view when things might go slower whatsoever reason.

Comment: angabriel, the problem with this is that the data appears in the html
when you inspect the page u'll see <div data-ng-bind="1+1">
with the first solution since we are replacing the elements text by html we are hiding the evaluated data

Comment: This requirement was not part of the original question. Anyway, I can still see 1+1 if I set a breakpoint on the first line in directive's link function.